# Checking for existing title in custom db query not working

Tags: plugin-development, query

I want to check if the title exists before the `wp_insert_post()` is triggered.

However, the condition seems not to work as expected:

```
if( $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . trim($titles_arr[$i]) . "' AND post_type=post", 'ARRAY_A') ) {
  // title do exist
  // don't save

} else {

  // ...perform save code

}
```

And it saves always no matter if it exists.

The funny part is that if the existing title i my db is e.g.: `The best title in the world` and slug `the-best-title-in-the-world` and for example one thing from the `trim($titles_arr[0])` (I am looping the array via foreach loop) array than the slug of that post that shouldn't be saved in the first place is called `the-best-title-in-the-world-2` and if I run my scirpt again it became `the-best-title-in-the-world-3` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [get_page_by_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) to get post by title.

I check for it on my system

```
$post_exist=get_page_by_title( 'Hello world!', ARRAY_A, 'post' );
    if( ! empty( $post_exist ) ) {
          echo 'title exist';
    } else {
        echo 'title not exist';
    }
```

Running successfully.

In your case it may be like

```
$title=trim($titles_arr[$i]);
$post_exist=get_page_by_title( $title, ARRAY_A, 'post' );
if( ! empty( $post_exist ) ) {
      echo 'title exist';
} else {
    echo 'title not exist';
}
```

see also:[Get WordPress Post ID from Post title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536682/get-wordpress-post-id-from-post-title)

Comment: Please, can you be more specific how can I use `get_page_by_title()` in my code in a loop with my `trim($titles_arr[$i])` and be aware that it has to be post (there are also attachments with the same name and this should be allowed; only the same title && post_type=post should by forbidden).

Comment: @Derfder I am updating my answer check it

Comment: I am getting error `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context `

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: try it i am updating my answer may be problem with empty because get_page_by_title returning object, changed it to array ( try to check what output comes from empty( get_page_by_title( trim($titles_arr[$i], ARRAY_A, 'post' ) ) )

Comment: May I ask you why you put `ARRAY_A, 'post'` inside the trim function?

Comment: I am updating code , running on my system,read this [get_page_by_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) for more info about function parameters